# How to upload image to server from url using flask python

Tags: python, opencv, flask

i need to get image from url(request.args.get) and upload the same image to server using python Flask.

```
  from flask import *
  app = Flask(__name__)
  @app.route('/success')
  def success():
     IMAGE= request.args.get('image')
     image=cv2.imread(IMAGE)
     ksize=(12,10)
     image = cv2.blur(image, ksize)
     cv2.imwrite(r"C:\Users\SiddanthShaiva\Desktop\ss_flask.jpg",image)
     return "successfull"
  app.run()
```

Till now, api/flask is running only if the image is present in my system ,if image is provided from other system it is not working, how to make api to run when image is loaded through any system?

N: The same api is hosted in the server, but requires image to be present in server and it is throwing error when image is not there in server.

So how to make this api working when image is given from any system?Please help, thanks :)

Comment: You can upload images using the `POST` HTTP method. Your route, however, does not allow the `POST` method, and does not access data sent through it. You can search [flask post image upload](https://www.google.com/search?q=flask+post+image+upload&rlz=1C1GCEA_enIL793IL793&oq=flask+post+image+upload&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.9895j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to find tutorials on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can post the image: [requests_post_files](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)

client:

```
import requests

requests.post(url, files={'image': open('image.jpg', 'rb')})
```

server:

```
from flast import request

binary_image = request.files['image'].read()
with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as fid:
    fid.write(binary_image)
```

Comment: im sorry , i didnot get you, can you please brief a bit

Comment: or maybe I didn't understand your problem correctly!

If the image is on the client machine and you want to send it to a server (a Flask api), you can post the image data directly rather sending a URL